# Detectar error en la carga dinámica de scripts

Tags: javascript

Tengo esta función, que carga dinamicamente los archivos que se le indiquen. Está pensada para cargar *scripts*:

```
function loadScripts( callback ) {
  var remain = 0,
      args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments ),
      idx = 0;

  makeScript( );

  function makeScript( ) {
    var curr = args[++idx],
        tmp;

    if( curr ) {
      ++remain;
      tmp = document.createElement( 'script' );
      tmp.setAttribute( 'charset', 'UTF-8' );
      tmp.setAttribute( 'type', 'text/javascript' );
      tmp.setAttribute( 'src', curr );
      tmp.onload = onLoad;
      document.head.appendChild( tmp );

      setTimeout( makeScript, 0 );
    }
  }

  function onLoad( ) {
    --remain;

    if( !remain )
      setTimeout( function( ) { callback( ); }, 0 );
  }
}
```

Lleva la cuenta del número que se ha cargado, y, cuando están todos, llama al argumento `callback`.

Funciona bien, pero ... tiene un problema: **no tiene en cuenta los errores**.

¿ Como la modifico para que detecte los errores en la carga, llamando igualmente a `callback( )` cuando se terminen de cargar todos los que **no han generado ningún error** ?

Comment: Existe una propiedad `HTMLScriptElement#onerror` que podría servir para capturar el fallo en la carga del script.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo ¿ No publicas una respuesta ? Podría ser lo que estoy buscando O_O

Comment: Puedo probar =P Voy a pensar el problema más en detalle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es posible cargar *scripts* de otra manera, con `XMLHttpRequest`, y probarlos con `eval`. Se puede hacer un `try catch` y determinar si pudo correr correctamente el *script*.

He hecho una función para descargar el archivo, que en este caso es el **.js**.

- El primer elemento es un booleano que dice si pudo descargar correctamente el archivo.
- El segundo elemento es el contenido del archivo.

```
function comprueba_y_descarga_URL(url) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest()
    http.open('GET', url, false)
    try{
        http.send()
        return [true,http.response]
    }catch(e)
    {
        return [false,""]
    }
}
```

Primero hay que declarar un array global, en alguna parte del código, que será la lista de las páginas que funcionan.

```
var funcionan=[]
```

Dentro del bloque `if( curr ) {` de `makeScript`, el código debe ser como la siguiente función.

Esto intenta descargar el *script* y ejecutarlo. Si puede, agrega un array a `funcionan`.

- El primer elemento es un booleano que dice si pudo ejecutar el script.
- El segundo elemento es la *URL* del archivo *JavaScript*.

```
++remain;
var existe=comprueba_y_descarga_URL(curr)
if(existe[0])
{
    try{
        eval(existe[1])
        funcionan.push( [true,curr] )
        onLoad()
    }catch(e)
    {
        funcionan.push( [false,curr] )
    }
    setTimeout( makeScript, 0 );
}
```

La otra manera de hacerlo, es meter el contenido del archivo descargado a `<script>`, mediante la propiedad `innerHTML`.

Dentro del `try` que está dentro de `if(existe[0])`, cambiarlo por lo siguiente:

```
tmp = document.createElement( 'script' );
tmp.onload = onLoad;
tmp.innerHTML=existe[1]
document.head.appendChild( tmp ); 
funcionan.push( [true,curr] )
```

Por último, en alguna parte del código, hacer que muestre el array `funcionan`. Puede ser de algunas de estas maneras.

- `console.log(funcionan)`
- `return funcionan`

Answer (score 2):

Utilizaría el siguiente planteamiento utilizando Promises, para sacar partido del método `Promise#all`:

```js
loadScripts('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.4/ol-debug.js', 'inventado')

function loadScript(src) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var script = document.createElement('script')
    script.onerror = reject
    script.onload = resolve
    //script.type = 'text/javascript'
    document.body.appendChild(script)
    script.src = src
  })
}

function loadScripts(...args) {
  return Promise.all(
    args.map( src =>
      loadScript(src)
        .then( ()=>{
          console.log(`El script ${src} se cargó correctamente`)
        })
        .catch( ()=>{
          console.log(`El script ${src} falló al cargarse`)
        })
    )
  )
    .then( ()=> console.log('Todos los scripts han sido cargados') )
}
```

Nota que con `Promise.all` los scripts se cargarán en paralelo.

Si por cuestión de dependencias, necesitáramos cargarlos secuencialmente, también es muy sencillo con Promises:

```js
loadScripts('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js')

function loadScript(src) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var script = document.createElement('script')
    script.onerror = reject
    script.onload = resolve
    //script.type = 'text/javascript'
    document.body.appendChild(script)
    script.src = src
  })
}

function loadScripts(...args) {
  return args.reduce( (promise, src) =>{
    
    return promise.then( ()=> 
    
      loadScript(src)
        .then( ()=>{
          console.log(`El script ${src} se cargó correctamente`)
        })
        .catch( ()=>{
          console.log(`El script ${src} falló al cargarse`)
        })
    
    );
    
  }, Promise.resolve())
    .then( ()=> console.log('Todos los scripts han sido cargados') )
}
```

---

Otra alternativa que se me ocurre, viene de la respuesta de @ArtEze, de manera que nos aseguramos de que el código no produce ningún error al evaluarse:

```js
// Nota que una Materialize depende de jquery
// Elimina la url hacia jquery para ver que pasa
var scripts = [
  '',
  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.4/ol-debug.js',
  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js', 
  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js'
  
];
loadScripts(...scripts)

function evaluateJS (code) {
  try {
    eval(code)
    return Promise.resolve(code)
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
}

function createScript (code) {
  var script = document.createElement('script')
  script.type = 'text/javascript'
  script.text = code
  document.body.appendChild(script)
  return Promise.resolve()
}

function loadScript (src) {
  // Petición para obtener el código
  return fetch(src)
    .then(res => res.text())
    // Evaluamos el código
    .then(evaluateJS)
    // En realidad nos podemos evitar esta parte 
    // ya que el código se ha evaluado ya, 
    // es redundante crear un script que evalúe el código
    //.then(createScript)
    // El código funciona sin errores
    .then( () => console.log(`El script ${src} se cargó correctamente`) )
    // Manejo de errores
    .catch((error) => console.log(`El script ${src} falló al cargarse:\n${error}`))
}

// Cargamos los scripts de forma secuencial
function loadScripts(...args) {
  return args.reduce( (promise, src) =>
    promise.then( ()=> loadScript(src) )
                            , Promise.resolve())
    .then( ()=> console.log(`Scripts cargados $: ${$}`) )
}
```

Comment: Al final, he adaptado la respuesta de ArtEze. Pero que conste que la tuya es una **pedazo** de respuesta. +1, y porqué no puedo darte mas.

Comment: Gracias @Trauma! :)